# How to run compiled vue project in django

Tags: python, django, vue.js

Previously, I know how to run *Vue* and *Django (jinja2 template)* together. 
by handling the custom delimiters, e.g `delimiters: ['[[', ']]']`.

But for some reason, my supervisor just need to *run the compiled vue project inside my existing django project*. As we can see, the vue has `npm run serve` or `yarn run serve` to run it.

Does django can handle this case? If yes, what I should do?

> In this case, we doesn't use direct web server like **nginx**, **apache**, etc to run.

Comment: I needed a react application's code in django admin so here's what i did: I compiled the code, and instead of mounting it into "root", I mounted it into the input. and placed it into the django admin additional javascript. Voila! it worked

Comment: @CharanjitSingh does it worked also for vue? Because when I compiled the vue project, and try to open the `.html` file, the browser redirected to `/404` url.

Answer (score 3):

[Charanjit Singh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9275249/charanjit-singh) answer is correct and your 404 problem is not related to vueJs. Since you are not using a direct web server you are making it harder.

Also If your vue application implements vue-router in history mode that'll cause even more problems since you're not using neither nginx or apache.
My only approach for this is [Haproxy](https://www.haproxy.com/products/haproxy-enterprise-edition/) that'll make your sub application handle those routes.

For example your app domain is `myawesomedomain.com` and your vue app is in `myawesomedomain.com/myvueapp` then you need to configure your Haproxy to let your vueapp handle all routes in `myawesomedomain.com/myvueapp/*`.

If you don't have a vue-router in your app then you need to place th `vueapp` folder in your deployed web folder and don't forget to add a routing rule for your html file (I don't know about Django but I did it with symfony and it is working)

```
Deployed
|
|_vueapp    ===> your compiled folder
|
|_htmlFile  ===> your html file
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, this is what I've been working on. I put the compiled `index.html` file from `dist/index.html` to `templates/vueapp/index.html` *(django templates folder)*. The other files & folders is put inside `static/` folder.

1. `templates/vueapp/index.html` => the compiled `html` file.
2. `static/vueapp/` *(includes: `css`, `js`, `fonts`, etc)*. => the compiled vue static files.

---

my `views.py`;

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView


class VueAppView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'vueapp/index.html'
```

and my `urls.py`;

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import (path, include)
from my_app.views import (HomeTemplateView, VueAppView)

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', HomeTemplateView.as_view()),
    path('vueapp/', VueAppView.as_view()),
]
```

also inside the `vueapp/index.html`. As we can see, I modified the source of `/static/vueapp/` and linked to the static folder.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=id>
  <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content="IE=edge">
    <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <link rel=icon href=/static/vueapp/favicon.ico>
    <title>siap-ums</title>
    <link rel=stylesheet href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900">
    <link rel=stylesheet href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons">
    <link href=/static/vueapp/css/chunk-01c619b4.ff54e24d.css rel=prefetch>
    <link href=/static/vueapp/css/chunk-308637dc.e4c5f763.css rel=prefetch>
    <link href=/static/vueapp/css/chunk-616b136f.404f3685.css rel=prefetch>
    <link href=/static/vueapp/js/app.876efdb8.js rel=preload as=script>
    <link href=/static/vueapp/js/chunk-vendors.2b11f5ad.js rel=preload as=script>
    <link href=/static/vueapp/css/chunk-vendors.a6a7bf01.css rel=stylesheet>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript><strong>We're sorry but siap-ums doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong></noscript>
    <div id=app></div>
    <script src=/static/vueapp/js/chunk-vendors.2b11f5ad.js></script><script src=/static/vueapp/js/app.876efdb8.js></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

> Every times the `vueapp` have changes, I must compile it first and do the same step as above.